# VBA code to close inactive workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried below VBA code to close the inactive workbook but it is not working.

```
Workbooks(VBA.Environ("Username") & ".xls").Close True
Workbooks(“p468904.xls").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks.Close Filename:=VBA.Environ("Username") & ".xls"
Workbooks(VBA.Environ("Username") & ".xls").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: **Not working** is insufficient information when asking about an error. The code code you've provided looks right and I've successfully tested a couple of them.

Comment: I am just opening the file with below code and closing the same with above code without any updation but the file is not closing. Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0, Password:="yourpassword"

Comment: Have you tried `Workbooks(myFileNameDir).Close SaveChanges:=True`?

Comment: @findwindow - Using `Workbooks("theWorkbook")` to reference an open workbook from the collection of open workbooks should not include the path.

Comment: I tried the code below code but not workingWorkbooks(myFileNameDir).Close SaveChanges:=True

Comment: Oh right. Ignore me.

Comment: I am getting error as invalid property use on below code.   Workbooks("theWorkbook")

Comment: What does it yield if you use *Application.DisplayAlerts = False* before the closing operation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close all workbooks except the one the code is in,

```
  For Each wkb In Workbooks
    If Not wkb Is ThisWorkbook Then wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' or True, depending
  Next wkb
```